# Converting a list of associations into a single association

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

How do i smartly join a List of Associations (eg. returned by ParallelTable) such that i get a single Association?

```
list = {<|"a" -> aValue|>, <|"b" -> bValue|>}
association = <|"a" -> aValue,"b" -> bValue|>
```

what line of code returns association created from list?
I tried various stock functions, but failed to find a fitting one.
It could work by calling `Join[(*elements of list seperated by comma*)]` but i do not know how to write such call.

My current workaround is:

```
assoc = <||>
Do[AppendTo[assoc, elem], {elem, list}]
```

Comment: `Join@@{<|"a" -> aValue|>, <|"b" -> bValue|>}`

Comment: `Merge[{<|"a" -> 1|>, <|"b" -> 3|>}, Identity]`?

Comment: And the winner is: `<|list|>`   ;P

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay  Either that, or `Merge[{<|"a" -> 1|>, <|"b" -> 3|>}, First]`, if you don't want lists in your result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is CW to record Kuba's comment which seems to be the simplest answer.

```
list = {<|"a" -> aValue|>, <|"b" -> bValue|>};
assoc = <|list|>
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> aValue, "b" -> bValue|>
> ```

From the Details section of [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html)

[image: quote]

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not exactly what the original question asked, I am adding this so that it exists for archival purposes. If the objective is to join two associations so that their members get joined, then use

```
Merge[{a1,a2},Catenate]
```

This command, takes `a1=<|"a11"->{{1,2},{3,4}},"a12"->{5,6}|>` and `a2=<|"a11"->{{11,22},{33,44}},"a12"->{7,8}|>` and produces

```
<|"a1" -> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {11, 22}, {33, 44}}, "a2" -> {5, 6, 7, 8}|>
```

Answer (score 0):

```wl
Join@@{<|key1->value1|>,<|key2->value2|>}
```

I use this. Join will not work and Catenate would return {value1,value2}.